# Is there a way to tell the instance of CL_OSQL_TEST_ENVIRONMENT to create views from mocked tables?

Tags: mocking, abap, test-double

Is there a way to tell the instance of `CL_OSQL_TEST_ENVIRONMENT` to create views from mocked tables?

For example I mock the following tables from the ERP system: `BSEG` and `BKPF`.

```
cl_osql_test_environment=>create(
  VALUE #(
    'BSEG'
    'BKPF'
  )
).
```

But this won't build me the `BSID` view in the OSQL test environment instead the calls to the view go directly to the contents of the underlying database. I would have to do the join by myself and then to mock the view `BSID` which I would want to avoid.

Is such a thing even supported, or maybe planned to be supported in the future?

Comment: I think I found something that would match my requirements. The class ist called `CL_CDS_TEST_ENVIRONMENT`. Once I have tested positively it I will post the answer to my own question.